# How to prevent Picker to fold into a submenu in SwiftUI macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, menu, picker

I'm trying to combine Picker and some buttons inside Menu in macOS SwiftUI app. Unfortunately Picker is folding into submenu automatically and I'm struggle to find a solution. How to prevent Picker to fold, or maybe there is a better solution around?

```swift
Menu("Budgets") {
    Picker("Budgets", selection: $account) {
        Button("Personal") {}.tag(1)
        Button("Business") {}.tag(2)
    }.labelsHidden()
                
    Divider()
                
    Button("New Budget…") {}
    Button("Manage Budgets…") {}
}
```

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `inline` picker style, like

```
 Picker("Budgets", selection: $account) {
      Button("Personal") {}.tag(1)
      Button("Business") {}.tag(2)
 }
 .labelsHidden()
 .pickerStyle(.inline)    // << here !!
```

[image]